# DropDownList in a UserControl inside a Repeater

Tags: drop-down-menu, user-controls, repeater

I have usercontrol - 'HolidayPackage.ascx' (which has a 'List Destinations' and is binded to a dropdown list - 'HolidayDestinations' with 'AutoPostBack = true') - The selection of the DropdownList is maintained in ControlState and I am binding the dropdown list on 'PreRender'.
I have another control - 'Holidays.ascx' (I have a Repeater that will have the 'HolidayPackage.ascx' control display multiple times based on number of packages available)
Now I have a page say 'test.aspx' which will display the 'Holiday.ascx' control - which will have 3 Holiday pacages displayed (so say 3 instances of 'HolidayPackage.ascx')

now when I select something in one dropdown (in one control) its resetting the other two dropdowns in other user controls .... say I select something on 1st control dropdown... the pagepostbacks and the 1st control selection is maintained... but the other two dropdownlist would loose their selected item... and the seletion changes to index 0...
any suggestions??? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am binding the dropdown list on 'PreRender'

This is where the error is. In order to maintain state, you should re-add dynamic controls during the Init stage (the page's/control's `OnInit()` event).